# Replicate curved lines in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to replicate the curved lines in this figure:

[image]

Using the curvature tool in Adobe Illustrator, I produced this:

[image]

How can I make the curves neat just like the original ones?

Comment: To be honest whats the problem in opening the original PDF? OR actually plotting the curves in illustrator?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The Curvature tool can do this [just fine](https://imgur.com/FTZsaQp).  I can't reproduce the bad result you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly wonky paths `:)`

I would merely use the **Pen Tool** to draw two curved paths, then create a **Blend** between them.

Actually, only one path needs to be drawn. You can then merely click-drag an end anchor holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key to create a second path (as I've done below.)

<sub>(Drawing paths and adding Blend.)</sub>
[image]

Thing is the curves are not exact blends between the left and right.

So afterwards, I'd *expand the blend* and adjust the individual paths.

<sub>(Expanding blend then adjusting paths.)</sub>
[image]

---

I've honestly never used the Curvature Tool - just never found a need for it myself. I imagine though, you want to draw just 2 anchors and curve the path between them. Similarly to how I've used the Pen Tool in the animation above. Your paths appear to be littered with superfluous anchor points. I think that is the primary issue.

The real key to smooth curves is to use as few anchor points as possible.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: To be fair, I don't see why the OP is having difficulty using the Curvature tool. It also works just fine on these curves. I can't reproduce the OPs bad result.

Comment: I don't know @BillyKerr - as posted I've honestly never used the Curvature Tool `:)` To be honest, not really sure why it's even in Illustrator - much like the Bounding Box - the functionality is already there, they just made a specific tool to do a specific thing. At least that's my take. I could, of course, be wrong.

Comment: @Scott - yeah not so useful for people like us who know how to use the Pen tool, but I think Adobe probably added it to give newbies an alternative way to make smooth curves automatically. It's a bit like the Pen tool, but with an automatic-pilot mode built in. I can't honestly understand how the OP ended up with such a poor result, because it's almost impossible to mess up the curves like that when using the curvature tool.

Comment: @BillyKerr I sometimes wonder if I take longer to do things merely because I use the same functionality that's been there for 20+ years and don't jump on new tools. I'm *still* not likely to jump to the Live Paint Bucket... `:)` -- And Adobe *does* **specifically** add features/tools for certain user groups -- the bounding box was *specifically* added to entice Corel users to switch, even though the Bounding Box has no unique function in itself. That's how I look at the Curvature tool. `:)`

Comment: Well the curvature tool implements b-spline interface and then under the hood make them beziers. Where is lots of advantages to b splines, though not necessarily if you convert them to beziers under the hood. The primary advatage in illustrator is that they are curveture continious without effort. But in general i agree with Scott adding tools to make people happy on migration is not a good solution.

Comment: Interesting @joojaa - so it draws better.. but as soon as you let go.. it's the same as everything else (bezier)?? Is that what you're saying? -- And I mistyped before. The Bounding Box does have one unique function  -- it gets in the way far more than any other feature `:)`

Comment: @Scott yeah i agree with bounding box. Yes the tool allows you to re edit it as a b-spline. But otherwise its saved as a normal bezier. A bit like the live corners act.

Comment: @Scott, thanks for your help! One question: How do you make the background graph transparently visible while working with pen tool? In my case, it is always hidden behind the curves I'm producing so that I cannot see the graph I'm replicating.

Comment: @ppp I just placed the raster image and then, using the transparency panel, set it's opacity to 50-60%, then chose `Object > Lock` so it can't be selected or moved. If it's being "hidden by curves" you draw.. make certain there's no fill on the paths you are drawing.

Comment: @Scott, thanks so much!